# How to select just parent and not inherit values

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. Game, FinalGame which extends Game and Participant who has list of game and list of FinalGame. Now I have problem. How to select just game and not finalGame. How to select Participant with just game and not finalGame.

In first option I tried:

```
select * from game g where {g.ID not in (select pl.game_id from PLAY_OFF_TABLE pl) }
```

but I am not sure if it is right.

In second option I tried;

```
select * from participant p left join game g1 on p.ID = g1.HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID
```

but this select all games including final. I have no idea how I can exclude final game

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GAME` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` enum('WIN','LOSE','DRAW') DEFAULT NULL,
  `RESULT` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID` (`HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID`),
  KEY `AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID` (`AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PLAY_OFF_GAME` (
  `GAME_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `POSITION` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GAME_ID`),
  KEY `GROUP_ID` (`GROUP_ID`),
  KEY `POSITION` (`POSITION`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PARTICIPANT` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

UPDATE:

```
select * from PARTICIPANT p left join GAME g1 on p.ID = g1.HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID join PLAY_OFF_GAME pl on g1.id = pl.GAME_ID where p.group_id = 441 and pl.GAME_ID is null
```

retun 0 rows

```
select * from PARTICIPANT p left join GAME g1 on p.ID = g1.HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID left join PLAY_OFF_GAME pl on g1.id = pl.GAME_ID where p.group_id = 441 and pl.GAME_ID is null
```

return 5

```
select * from PARTICIPANT p left join GAME g1 on p.ID = g1.HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID left join PLAY_OFF_GAME pl on g1.id = pl.GAME_ID where p.group_id = 441
```

return all participant 8 but also final game which I want to exclude

Comment: Join your game table with finalgame table on its keys - then join finalgame with participant on its key and just select rows distinct from game and participant.

Comment: what about some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query would select `GAME` rows that do not have a corresponding `PLAY_OFF_GAME`, but a join is probably much quicker:

```
SELECT *
FROM GAME g
LEFT JOIN PLAY_OFF_GAME pog ON g.ID=pog.GAME_ID
WHERE pog.GAME_ID IS NULL;
```

For the second question, you can do the same trick:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 (SELECT p1.*, g.ID 
  FROM PARTIPANT p1
  LEFT JOIN GAME g1 ON p1.ID=g1.HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID
  LEFT JOIN PLAY_OFF_GAME pog1 ON g1.ID=pog1.GAME_ID
  WHERE pog1.GAME_ID IS NULL)
 UNION
 (SELECT p2.*, NULL
  FROM PARTICIPANT p2
  JOIN GAME g2 ON p2.ID=g2.HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID
  JOIN PLAY_OFF_GAME pog2 ON g2.ID=pog2.GAME_ID)) AS tmp;
```

Query may have typos. First selects Particpants in a game, or in no game, but it's excluding the participants only in final games. The second select fills those back in, ignoring the game.

Also:

- To select all participants, and not just 'home' participants, not in a game or in a non-playoff game, add `OR p.ID=g.AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID` to the `ON` clause. (I'm following your example, but the description seems to be at odds.
- Should there be a foreign key constraint on `PLAY_OFF_GAME`? E.g., `CONSTRAINT play_off_game_fk FOREIGN KEY (GAME_ID) REFERENCES GAME (ID)`?

Comment: why u are using join instead of left join in second example ? I try both options but I think it works only with left join. With join it return 0 rows

Comment: 'FROM PARTICIPANT p JOIN GAME g ON ... LEFT JOIN PLAY_OFF_GAME pog'. So it's a join from PARTICPANT to GAME because the whole point is to find participants in games, but not PLAY_OFF_GAMES, which is why the second join is a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: but this example has one big mistake it doesnt return all participant. I want to return all participant and their game.

Comment: I updated the answer to fill in the missing participants. If there's a problem, could you post a data dump for testing?